# Assembler signed comparison

Tags: assembly, x86, comparison

(Using the X86 instruction set with AT&T syntax.)

I am currently developing a program to find the smallest number in a list of `long` values.

The values are assigned as follows

```
data_items: .long 13,-5,-8,4,-120
```

The problem that I'm having is the comparison of the values because they could be negative. I am looking on my data_items as signed values, on some answers on stackoverflow the use of `jg` - jump if greater is proposed. But it is not working for me, or i may be using it wrong.

I wrote a little "test"

```
movl $-7, %ebx    #write -7 to register ebx
movl $2, %ecx     #write 2 to register ecx

cmpl %ebx, %ecx   #compare -7 and 2
jl end_loop       #if -7 is less than 2, jump
movl $77, %ebx    # move 77 to register ebx

end_loop:
```

The result (in register %ebx) should be -7 (or actually 249 because its two complement's), but it is 77.

How can compare signed values? Do i have to determine if they are signed, keep that in mind, and if they are signed negate them before comparing?

Comment: The x86 offers sets of jmp instruction for unsigned compares, and signed compares.   YOu need to look up the jmp opcodes and see which ones are for signed compares.

Comment: By the way, -7 would be 4294967289, not 249. You have dwords there.

Comment: @harold you are right, because I am using a long datatype. But i got confused because when i do "echo $?" i get 249 back, which is -7 complement in 8bit view. Maybe it cuts the leading zeros?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your basic problem is not signedness (`jl` is correct for a signed comparison; if you wanted unsigned you'd use `jb`) but the order of operands to the `cmp` instruction.

Here are a couple of memory aid ideas:

`cmp $42, %ecx` is a legal instruction, but `cmp %ecx, $42` isn't. So if you think of the second operand as "the variable I'm testing" and the first operand as "the value I'm comparing it to", then the natural wording of the jump instruction "Jump if the variable is less than the value" will be correct.

Or, if you don't like that, remember that `cmp` is like a subtraction that throws the result away and only stores the flags, and when you read an instruction like `sub %ebx, %ecx` as a sentence, the easiest way to make it grammatically correct is to pronounce the comma as "from". "Subtract ebx *from* ecx" - and if the result is less than 0, `jl` will jump.

Your way of reading the instruction, by taking the "less than" represented by the `jl`, and inserting it in place of the comma in the `cmp` instruction, leads to the wrong answer.

Answer (score 1):

They are signed because you said so, you can never test if something is signed. Any bit pattern is also a valid unsigned number. There is nothing to distinguish them except in how you use them.

In your example, it compares `ecx` with `ebx` and then goes to `end_loop` if `ecx <s ebx`, which it isn't.

Comment: thank you for your answer! I marked the other answer from Wumpus Q. Wumbley because i had a understanding problem with the cmp instruction - he made a good example to remember it for me.